# WIndows 8.1 desktop GeoLocation project missing references

Tags: c#, geolocation, windows-8.1

I'm beginner with C#. I've wrote a very simple Console project to get location coordinates on my PC.

```
using LocationProvider;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestLocationProvider
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            obtenerPosicion();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public async static void obtenerPosicion()
        {
            GPSAccess gps = new GPSAccess();
            Task<GPSData> longRunningTask = gps.GetCurrentPosition();
            GPSData result = await longRunningTask;
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

The LocationProvider namespace is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.Devices.Geolocation;

namespace LocationProvider
{
    public class GPSAccess
    {
        public async Task<GPSData> GetCurrentPosition()
        {
            GPSData data;
            Geolocator loc = new Geolocator();
            try
            {
                data = new GPSData();
                loc.DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High;
                Geoposition pos = await loc.GetGeopositionAsync();
                var lat = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude;
                var lang = pos.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude;
                data.latitud = Math.Truncate(lat) * 100 + (lat - Math.Truncate(lat)) * 60;
                data.longitud = Math.Truncate(lang) * 100 + (lang - Math.Truncate(lang)) * 60;
                return data;
            }
            catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
            {
                // handle error
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Im using references for Windows 8.1 
- Windows.Devices
- Windows.Foundations
and .NET 4.5
- System.Threading.Tasks

However Im getting an error on the line

```
Geoposition pos = await loc.GetGeopositionAsync();
```

that says:

> `IAsyncOperation<Geoposition>` does not contain a definition for
>   `GetAwaiter` and not extension method `GetAwaiter` accepting a first
>   argument of type `IAsyncOperation<Geoposition>` could be found (are
>   you missing a using directive for `System`?)

Am I forgetting some reference?

Comment: You are using UWP classes on a .net Classic project, add a reference to System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll, that should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you Gusman Now it dont gives error at compilation but at runtime returns 

System.Exception occurred
  HResult=0x800700E8
  Message=The pipe is being closed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700E8)
  Source=mscorlib

Comment: Create a new question as this is a different error.